# How do I import Bootstrap in SvelteKit, Recommended Way?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, svelte, sveltekit

I am building a site with SvelteKit. As of now I included Bootstrap 5 in my project by adding it to the app.html file provided by the SvelteKit Skeleton project:

```
<!-- Bootstrap styles and javascript --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Now when building the site with `npm run build` the bootstrap modules are not loaded anymore.

Comment: What about using npm https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download-npm?

Comment: There exist libraries like [`sveltestrap`](https://sveltestrap.js.org/), that wrap Bootstrap for Svelte usage by the way.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I used npm to install bootstrap, my problem is I dont know how to include / import it properly so its still recognized after I build the site

Comment: @H.B. Unfortunately I found out about this after I finished my site. From what I can tell is that I would have to rewrite the bootstrap components I used in my site which is too much work for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably just import the files in the top level [`+layout.svelte`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-layout-svelte).

Something along the lines of:

```html
<script>
  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
  import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
</script>
<slot />
```

Vite should take care of the rest. (You can also import the non-minified versions for a better dev experience, as the build should minify anyway.)

Note that this will cause issues with server-side rendering, and generally it is recommended to import components like this as necessary:

```js
import Alert from 'bootstrap/js/dist/alert';

// or, specify which plugins you need:
import { Tooltip, Toast, Popover } from 'bootstrap';
```

You can also import style sources rather than the compiled styles.
SvelteKit uses Vite, so the [respective Vite guidelines](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/vite/#import-bootstrap) should be applicable.

If you just want to import everything in an SSR compatible way, you can use [a URL-import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#static-assets) and add a script tag to the `head`, e.g.:

```html
<script>
  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
  import scriptSrc from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js?url';
</script>
<svelte:head>
  <script src={scriptSrc}></script>
</svelte:head>
<slot />
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried the last one and now use the URL-import and everything seems to be working. Thank you very much :)

Comment: OMG you saved my life! I've been fighting with this for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and correct way to add Bootstrap to SvelteKit is by using the `svelte-add` package, which handles all the configuration for you.
To add use:

```bash
npx svelte-add@latest bootstrap
```

then:

```bash
npm install
```